# How to determine a FOL structure which satisfies a given formula

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

I have the task:

Consider the formula $\forall x (Q(x,b) \to Q(b,x))$ where $Q$ is a binary predicate symbol and $b$ is an individual constant. State

> i) one non-satisfying, and
>
> ii) one satisfying

FOL structure (with justification).

---

Progress so far:

First, define what satisfiability means in relation to a formula. Since the formula being considered is of the conditional form, a structure $\mathfrak{M}$ needs to be found such $Q(x,b)$ is not satisfied or $Q(b,x)$ is satisfied or $Q(x,b)$ and $Q(b,x)$ are satisfied.

Am I on the right track? If so, what can I do as a next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct for question ii), not for question i).

i) You should find a structure $\mathfrak{M}$ such that $\mathfrak{M} \models \lnot \forall x (Q(x,b) \to Q(b,x))$, i.e. $\mathfrak{M} \models \exists x (Q(x,b) \land \lnot Q(b,x))$. It means that in $\mathfrak{M}$ you should have an element $x$ such that $Q(x,b)$ is satisfied and $Q(b,x)$ is not satisfied.
Now, let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the structure whose domain is $\{0,1\}$ and such that $b$ is interpreted by $1$ and $Q(x,y)$ is interpreted as $x < y$: then, $Q(0,b)$ but $\lnot Q(b,0)$ in $\mathfrak{M}$, hence $\mathfrak{M} \models \exists x (Q(x,b) \land \lnot Q(b,x))$ taking $x = 0$ as witness.

ii) The formula $\forall x (Q(x,b) \to Q(b,x))$ is satisfied by any structure $\mathfrak{M}$ where a symmetric relation $Q$ can be defined. For instance...

Comment: The most simple symmetric relation that I can think of would be the identity symbol "=". I'm not sure how to formalize this though.

Comment: @Oscar - Good idea! Fix a domain and an interpretation for $b$, and you are done.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. For a domain, it seems there are several choices that would be sufficient. For instance, here the domain could be $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\{1,2,3\}$. I will choose $\mathbb{Z}$. Here I let the interpretation $Q(x,b)$ be the identity $x = b$, however for the interpretation b there are also multiple choices, such as $b = 2$. Have I correctly formalized my suggestion?

Comment: @Oscar - Yes, that's right. If you want to minimize the effort, in your structure $\mathfrak{M}$ take $\{0\}$ as domain, $b = 0$ and $Q(x,y)$ as $x = y$: then $\mathfrak{M} \models \forall x (Q(x,b) \to Q(b,x))$ trivially (the only case to check is $x = 0$).

Comment: Good point. Also, the fact that you used the notation also helps my understanding. Thanks for helping me understand the problem, your answer has been accepted.